# Implementing Hive UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a hive table with ip_address column. How can I find country, city and Zip code from that ip_address column?

I see a udf written:

https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive-geoip

How do I utilize udf in hive? Can I create function name myself?

The udf says we need separate database:

http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz

How do I implement that database on Hive?

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Rio

Answer (score 0):

You utilize UDFs in Hive by adding the jars and creating temporary functions as described by your first link.

```
add file GeoIP.dat;
add jar geo-ip-java.jar;
add jar hive-udf-geo-ip-jtg.jar;
create temporary function geoip as 'com.jointhegrid.hive.udf.GenericUDFGeoIP';
```

You may change the function name to whatever you would prefer, simply replace the word after "temporary function" from "geoip" to whatever you want.

Adding the database you linked to is a matter of downloading it to your unix server and then unzipping it using gzip. Once it is in the GeoIP.dat format, move it and the jars you've downloaded into the your /users/(your username)/ directory and then run the code as instructed above. The files must be in your top directory or else explicitly targeted during your add file and add jar statements. by that I mean instead of `add file GeoIP.dat;` it must be `add file /users/wertz/downloads/GeoIP.dat;` for example.

Finally, by looking at the code the UDF needs three arguments. The first argument is the IP address, the second argument is what you're looking for (choices appear to be COUNTRY_NAME, COUNTRY_CODE, AREA_CODE, CITY, DMA_CODE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, METRO_CODE, POSTAL_CODE, REGION, ORG, or ID) and the final value is the filename of the GeoIP database, which hopefully you have not changed from GeoIP.dat

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I create Jar file? where do I run "add file add jar geo-ip-java.jar;" (on hive, command line etc)?

Comment: You do not create the jar files for this, just download what is contained in the links you originally posted. on your Unix system, run hive and then run that command

Comment: I did git clone "hive-geoip" repository
Then I ran below command and I get error (can you please try at your end?):
hive> add jar geo-ip-java.jar;
geo-ip-java.jar does not exist
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: geo-ip-java.jar does not ex

Comment: I do not yet have experience with Github, but the error tells me that the files are not where they are expected to be. when you run the command as stated it checks /users/(your username)/geo-ip-java.jar and if it doesn't find it then it returns that error. I'm guessing what happened is the Git clone copied the files to your unix/linux directory. you need to navigate to your directory in linux/unix and run `ls` if the files are there, you need to run the following command while still in that directory `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal (name of file) /users/(your username)/`

Comment: There is no geo-ip-java.jar (any jar) file when I got from GIt. There are only .java files.

Comment: I do see what you're talking about. I'm not as much of a java expert so maybe someone else can help with that. I did flag a friend who knows java and he said to run `javac GenericUDFGeoIP.java` and then `jar -cvf geo-ip-java.jar GenericUDFGeoIP.class`
as that will create the jar for one of them, but I can't figure out what needs to be jar'd for the other